# SQL JOIN to get a list of intventory items and alternate items

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, sybase

I have a database representing retail items. Some items have multiple scancode, but are in essence the same item, ie. their name, cost, and retail will ALWAYS be the same. To model this, [the database has the following structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3daa6/2):

```
Inventory_Table

INV_PK | INV_ScanCode | INV_Name | INV_Cost | INV_Retail
  1    | 000123456789 |  Muffins | 0.15     | 0.30    
  2    | 000987654321 |  Cookie  | 0.25     | 0.50    
  3    | 000123454321 |  Cake    | 0.45     | 0.90    


Alternates_Table

ALT_PK | INV_FK | ALT_ScanCode
  1    |   2    | 000999888777
  2    |   2    | 000666555444
  3    |   2    | 000333222111
```

Now say I want a listing of all the scan codes in the database, how would I join the tables to get the following output:

```
ScanCode     | Name    | Cost | Retail
000123456789 | Muffins | 0.15 | 0.30
000987654321 | Cookie  | 0.25 | 0.50 
000999888777 | Cookie  | 0.25 | 0.50
000666555444 | Cookie  | 0.25 | 0.50
000333222111 | Cookie  | 0.25 | 0.50
000123454321 | Cake    | 0.45 | 0.90
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3daa6/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `union`:

```
SELECT it.INV_ScanCode, it.INV_Name, it.INV_Cost, it.INV_Retail 
FROM   Inventory_Table AS it
UNION ALL
SELECT at.ALT_ScanCode, it.INV_Name, it.INV_Cost, it.INV_Retail 
FROM   Inventory_Table AS it
  INNER JOIN Alternate_Table AS at
  ON at.INV_FK = INV_PK
```

`UNION ALL` is the faster choice when you know the rows won't repeat between the two sets of results (so the DB doesn't need to check for duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT it.INV_ScanCode, it.INV_Name, it.INV_Cost, it.INV_Retail 
FROM   Inventory_Table AS it

union all

SELECT at.ALT_ScanCode, it.INV_Name, it.INV_Cost, it.INV_Retail 
FROM   Alternate_Table AS at
inner join Inventory_Table AS it on at.INV_FK = it.INV_PK
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3daa6/6)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the query, you need to fetch everything from the inventory table.  Then you need to select all the alternates using both `inventory_table` and `alternates_table`.  This suggests `union all` for the overall query:

```
select scancode, name, cost, retail
from inventory_table i
union all
select a.scancode, i.name, i.cost, i.retail
from inventory_table i join
     alternates_table a
     on a.inv_fk = i.inv_pk
```